# Why do I get this error with phpmailer when trying to send an email?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

Error:

```
2021-03-19 15:17:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP t24sm3903607qto.23 - gsmtp
2021-03-19 15:17:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2021-03-19 15:17:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [24.233.165.10]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-03-19 15:17:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-03-19 15:17:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2021-03-19 15:17:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2021-03-19 15:17:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [24.233.165.10]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-03-19 15:17:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2021-03-19 15:17:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2021-03-19 15:17:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-03-19 15:17:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2021-03-19 15:17:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
2021-03-19 15:17:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t24sm3903607qto.23 - gsmtp
2021-03-19 15:17:51 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials t24sm3903607qto.23 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2021-03-19 15:17:51 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-03-19 15:17:51 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection t24sm3903607qto.23 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

My Code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
 
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
 
// Instantiation and passing [ICODE]true[/ICODE] enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
 
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'myemail@gmail.com';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*************';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption, [ICODE]ssl[/ICODE] also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
 
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('myemail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'Recipients');     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('');
    $mail->addReplyTo('myemai@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    //$mail->addCC('');
    //$mail->addBCC('');
 
    // Attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('');         // Add attachments
    //$mail->addAttachment('');
 
    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
 
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

I have less secure apps enabled.
I have IMAP enabled.
Two step verification off.
I downloaded the latest version from github.
The email is my email and does work.
What should I do?
I am trying this from my localhost on xampp.
My password is correct. Why does this happen?

[image: Less secure apps on]

Comment: What `$mail->addAddress('');` does in your code?

Comment: just allows more recipients I believe

Comment: More recipients without email address and name? Where's the sense?

Comment: ok I removed it

Comment: Most probably other additions without values also will cause similar problems, pls, cleanup it first. Don't use methods that shouldn't be used in the case.

Comment: ok I will clean it up

Comment: I cleaned it up

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wanted to use `smtp.gmail.com` you have `smpt...` instead.

Comment: I edited it. I still get an error

Comment: did you read error message? Especially advice Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials . TIP it may be required to login into your Gmail account and allow selected server/IP to send the emails this way.

Comment: My credentials are correct.

Comment: I read that and I still get this error

Comment: What about second part? Login to Gmail and allowing services?

Comment: I have imap and pop allowed and less secure apps enabled and I did the captcha

Comment: And did you check your incoming mails? Most probably you get just notification about locked try of login, check SPAM and other incoming folders to make sure. Also most probably in the same time you received similar alert on your connected mobile phone with directions how to unlock it.

Comment: No I did not get an email. I checked. I still get the error saying bad credentials.

Comment: I just signed out of google and back in.

Comment: My credentials are correct

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563?hl=en&ref_topic=7188673 here's what (in my opinion) blocks you, you need investigate at your account to make it working. Unfortunately can't find now how to change it.

Comment: I allowed everything. I just don't know why it won't work. Is it case sensitive? I think so.

Comment: Evidently not everything, just examined your code, works as required but need that change I mentioned in Google, pls check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited your question several times, each time changing its meaning, that should be avoided in future as it generates tones of comments. Instead next time pls, read error messages and fix them before asking. What you did wrong (in order of appearance)

1. Don't use assigning methods without values just *for future* like `$mail->addAddress('');`, `$mail->addCC('')`, etc, it will cause errors.
2. Use proper SMTP server address.
3. Use proper credentials. Of course login and password **are** case sensitive.
4. Turn **ON** 'Less secure applications' on your Gmail account if still have problem with credentials errors. It can be done at the security tab as shown at screenshot

[image: Turn on less secure apps in your account]

Comment: less secure apps are enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will next time remove the empty stuff and then post my real question

Comment: I tried your code with my credentials and mail arrives (it didn't before setting the *less secure* thing) TBH have no more ideas.

Comment: ok. How long did you wait before it worked after you turned on less secure apps

Comment: I dunno, maybe 15 seconds

Comment: should i use ssl or tls

Comment: TLS should be ok, just tested your code only changed credentials, that worked.

Answer (score -1):

It's this typo:

```
$mail->Host       = 'smpt.gmail.com';
```

That should be:

```
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
```

The error message itself says that the host name could not be found, which is entirely expected given that it's wrong.