# php smtp cannot sent email in ubuntu server

Tags: php, smtp, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to send mails for forgot password .The code works fine on local machine and i can recieve emails. But when i deploy on ubuntu server version 20.04 I get Error.

```
?php

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server example

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server

$mail->Username   = 'username@gmail.com'; // SMTP account username example
$mail->Password   = 'password';        // SMTP account password example

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';    
// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->SetFrom("username@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
$mail->AddAddress('to_user@gmail.com');     // Add a recipient
$mail->send()
?>
```

I have tried with 465 port and changing to $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
But no luck
I have also enabled less secure apps in gmail and no connection is blocked in gmail also port is open in ubuntu server 587, 465 Still no luck.
Let me know if am wrong in any aspect of opening ports etc ..
Any help would be appreciated

Edit: The error looks something like this

```
2021-03-20 12:32:33 Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
2021-03-20 12:32:33 Connection: opened
2021-03-20 12:32:33 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:33 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f2sm8786335pfq.129 - gsmtp"
2021-03-20 12:32:33 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f2sm8786335pfq.129 - gsmtp
2021-03-20 12:32:33 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 103.117.180.121
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-03-20 12:32:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2021-03-20 12:32:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 103.117.180.121
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
2021-03-20 12:32:34 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [103.117.180.121]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-03-20 12:32:34 Auth method requested: UNKNOWN
2021-03-20 12:32:34 Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH
2021-03-20 12:32:34 Auth method selected: LOGIN
2021-03-20 12:32:34 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2021-03-20 12:32:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
2021-03-20 12:32:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2021-03-20 12:32:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: bmluamFzdG9ybTU1NTVAZ21haWwuY29t
2021-03-20 12:32:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:35 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
2021-03-20 12:32:35 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2021-03-20 12:32:35 CLIENT -> SERVER: dmlja3lAMTEwNQ==
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 AMiGCo8rutfSvEneAss3krvj8-TcwiFNjox9TLQZAYp0eH4CisKZ6Ss0njU4ZLe824Xt9"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 AMiGCo8rutfSvEneAss3krvj8-TcwiFNjox9TLQZAYp0eH4CisKZ6Ss0njU4ZLe824Xt9"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 1vhLWdKAHx3F1CpeyCpDoW0-8wVcFionwIjNdKfzuOmZsUisBB9trv-52_4oxkDP>"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 AMiGCo8rutfSvEneAss3krvj8-TcwiFNjox9TLQZAYp0eH4CisKZ6Ss0njU4ZLe824Xt9534-5.7.14 1vhLWdKAHx3F1CpeyCpDoW0-8wVcFionwIjNdKfzuOmZsUisBB9trv-52_4oxkDP>"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again."
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 AMiGCo8rutfSvEneAss3krvj8-TcwiFNjox9TLQZAYp0eH4CisKZ6Ss0njU4ZLe824Xt9534-5.7.14 1vhLWdKAHx3F1CpeyCpDoW0-8wVcFionwIjNdKfzuOmZsUisBB9trv-52_4oxkDP>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again."
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 Learn more at"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 AMiGCo8rutfSvEneAss3krvj8-TcwiFNjox9TLQZAYp0eH4CisKZ6Ss0njU4ZLe824Xt9534-5.7.14 1vhLWdKAHx3F1CpeyCpDoW0-8wVcFionwIjNdKfzuOmZsUisBB9trv-52_4oxkDP>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f2sm8786335pfq.129 - gsmtp"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 AMiGCo8rutfSvEneAss3krvj8-TcwiFNjox9TLQZAYp0eH4CisKZ6Ss0njU4ZLe824Xt9534-5.7.14 1vhLWdKAHx3F1CpeyCpDoW0-8wVcFionwIjNdKfzuOmZsUisBB9trv-52_4oxkDP>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f2sm8786335pfq.129 - gsmtp
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv534-5.7.14 AMiGCo8rutfSvEneAss3krvj8-TcwiFNjox9TLQZAYp0eH4CisKZ6Ss0njU4ZLe824Xt9534-5.7.14 1vhLWdKAHx3F1CpeyCpDoW0-8wVcFionwIjNdKfzuOmZsUisBB9trv-52_4oxkDP>534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f2sm8786335pfq.129 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2021-03-20 12:32:36 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 closing connection f2sm8786335pfq.129 - gsmtp"
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection f2sm8786335pfq.129 - gsmtp
2021-03-20 12:32:36 Connection: closed
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

also my ssl is not activated Please let me know if this can be issue

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please update your question with more details or it will be closed and/or downvoted. Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated with the error messages @biesior Please help if possible

Comment: *2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed...* etc, there are some suggestions and links in the error logs, you should follow them and check if you can fix your problem. Also read my comments in similar topic from yesterday - maybe you'll find some additional clues: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66710606/1066240

Comment: But it works on localhost i.e local machine but when i deploy on server i get this issue @biesior

Comment: Check clues suggested in error logs. It may happen that i.e. your prod server uses an IP previously used by Chinese cracker's claster ;) dunno, first tbing is to make sure you are using proper credentials (letter case is important) and your google account has enabled access for "less secure apps"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one week of try finally I found a solution
I followed this video and found a solution
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBbmo1pi5B0

Basically It tells to enable recatpcha
I don't know the exact reason but this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have the error described here:
2021-03-20 12:32:36 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14

Possible the password is really incorect or you can go here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps to allow less secure applications to access your account. You need to switch the button to ON.

Comment: If password is incorrect then it should have not worked on my local server.  Also as I have mentioned I have enabled less secure apps

Comment: Also in error you have a link that can answer to your problem. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754, one of them is: Make sure your mail app isn't set to check for new email too frequently. If your mail app checks for new messages more than once every 10 minutes, the app’s access to your account could be blocked.